# How to generate a custom alphanumeric id for domain class in grails?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Guys

I have a doming names Customers i have been using the default auto incremental value or the GORM to handle my ID. But , now i wanted to change the id from  to auto generating 6 alphanumeric characters ,you know they must be unique ? so how can i do that ? please?

Comment: is there any possibility of getting same random ? at any point in time? since ,i use this for my database id identification ##

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this dear :

```
public static String getAlphaNumbericRandom(int length) {
         String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

            int numberOfCodes = 0;//controls the length of alpha numberic string
            String code = "";
            while (numberOfCodes < length) {
                char c = chars.charAt((int) (Math.random() * chars.length()));
                code += c;
                numberOfCodes++;
            }
            return code;
        }
```

Call this method and pass the length (e.g 4,5 etc)

Comment: nice solution, but how do u integerate it in grails like static mappings ={ id generator = 'to call this fucntion' } i was thinking to create a sequence in database ? that i can refer it like above  id generator sequence_name

Comment: thats fine..yes u can integrate this fun to get random value.

Answer (score 0):

defining id attribute as ObjectId can generate id of 12 alphanumeric characters